# About unfairness of envy-free cake-cutting for 2 people in a real situation.

Tags: probability

For those who don’t know envy-free cake-cutting, this is an explanation of envy-free cake cutting from Wikipedia.

> An envy-free cake-cutting  is a division of a heterogeneous resource ("cake") that satisfies the envy-free criterion, namely, that every partner feels that their allocated share is at least as good as any other share, according to their own subjective valuation.
>
> For 2 persons the protocol proceeds as follows: one person ("the cutter") cuts the cake into two pieces; the other person ("the chooser") chooses one of the pieces; the cutter receives the remaining piece.

I understood the protocol works mathematically.
But in a real situation, I think the latter one will have some slight advantages over the first one.

To make it simple, here I suppose the cake is a line segment $[-1,1]$. The person A will cut line by choosing some point where A thinks center on the line, later B will take either of two he thinks big. Suppose A and B is independently identically prejudiced about center point location which is affected by their mood. For example,
$$P(-0.1) = 0.1 $$
$$P(0) = 0.8 $$  $$P(0.1) = 0.1 $$

When A’s mood is x, A will cut the line at x.  When B’s mood is y and is bigger than A’s mood x, B will chose the right segment. When y is smaller than x, B will chose the left segment. When y equals x, B will chose whichever equally randomly.

By doing simple probabilistic arithmetic, I concluded that B’s expected length of line is bigger than the half of the original line segment despite A and B have same prejudice.

Any way to avoid this unfairness? Any papers about this topic? Thanks.

Comment: Envy-free, as a criterion, is not really related to fairness.  A will be envy-free using this method.  If you want fairness, you can e.g. cut the line randomly and assign the pieces randomly (and allow trade if both agree).  Then it's fair.  :)

Comment: Also, if A is willing to take a small risk that they will be envious at the end, and assuming A knows B's probability distribution, then cutting at $x_A$ may not the A's optimal strategy to maximize A's utility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume A and B will never know their and opponent's probability distribution. 
After I saw your first post, I noticed we just have to pick the cutter randomly from A and B to achieve fairness and envy-freeness at the same time. Maybe this will be the answer to my question. Well, this will lead to another question though. Do we really need randomness to achieve fairness in the sense I defined and also envy-free at the same time.
Anyway thank you so much.